# RoR: Validation of field through model-level validation

Tags: validation, activerecord

In Ruby on Rails, I have a table called Person. It has a field `name`. The table already has many rows. Some of them also have name as `nil`. I am fine with the records that already have `nil` in the `name` field but moving forward I want to mandate filling of name field when someone creates a new Person entry. I am using Active Record Validation to implement this:

in `app/models/person.rb`

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :name, :presence => true
end
```

Will this mess up my Person table, since I already have some entries with nil in the name field.

Answer (score 1):

Validate only while creating new entry

`validates :name, :presence => true, on::create`